# NSE lazyeval::lazy vs. substitute when referring to variable names

Tags: r, dplyr, lazy-evaluation

I'm still trying to wrap my head around non-standard evaluation and how it's used in `dplyr`. I'm having trouble understanding why lazy evaluation is important when the function arguments are variable names, and so the original context's environment doesn't seem important.

In the code below, the function `select3()` uses lazy evaluation, but fails (I believe) because it tries to follow the variable name `order` all the way to `base::order`.

Is it okay to use substitute as I have in my `select4()`, or is there some other way I should implement this function? When would it actually be important to save the original environment, when I really want those arguments to refer to variables?

Thank you!

```
library(dplyr)
library(lazyeval)
# Same as dplyr::select
select2 <- function(.data, ...) {
  select_(.data, .dots = lazy_dots(...))
}

# I want to have two capture groups of variables, so I need named arguments.
select3 <- function(.data, group1, group2) {
  out1 <- select_(.data, .dots = lazy(group1))
  out2 <- select_(.data, .dots = lazy(group2))

  list(out1, out2)
}


df <- data.frame(x = 1:2, y = 3:4, order = 5:6)

# select3 seems okay at first...
df %>% select2(x, y)
df %>% select3(x, y)


# But fails when the variable is a function defined in the namespace
df %>% select2(x, order)
df %>% select3(x, order)
# Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'datafile' not found


# Using substitute instead of lazy works. But I'm not sure I understand the 
# implications of doing this.
select4 <- function(.data, group1, group2) {
  out1 <- select_(.data, .dots = substitute(group1))
  out2 <- select_(.data, .dots = substitute(group2))

  list(out1, out2)
}

df %>% select4(x, order)
```

**PS** on a related note, is this a bug or intended behavior?

```
select(df, z)
# Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'z' not found

# But if I define z as a numeric variable it works.
z <- 1
select(df, z)
```

---

### Update

A. Webb points out below that the environment is important for `select` because the special functions like `one_of` can use objects from it.

### Update 2

I used to have an ugly hack as a fix, but here's a much better way; I should've known that even `lazy` has a standard evaluation counter-part `lazy_`

```
select6 <- function(.data, group1, group2) {
  g1 <- lazy_(substitute(group1), env = parent.frame())
  g2 <- lazy_(substitute(group2), env = parent.frame())

  out1 <- select_(.data, .dots = g1)
  out2 <- select_(.data, .dots = g2)

  list(out1, out2)
}

# Or even more like the original...

lazy_parent <- function(expr) {
  # Need to go up twice, because lazy_parent creates an environment for itself
  e1 <- substitute(expr)
  e2 <- do.call("substitute", list(e1), envir = parent.frame(1))

  lazy_(e2, parent.frame(2))
}

select7 <- function(.data, group1, group2) {
  out1 <- select_(.data, .dots = lazy_parent(group1))
  out2 <- select_(.data, .dots = lazy_parent(group2))

  list(out1, out2)
}
```

Comment: I don't think the `select3` issue is expected behavior. If you issue an `attach(df)`, the `select3` call works. I'm not sure how `lazy` is implemented, see also https://github.com/hadley/lazyeval/commit/f8599c9305bac27408ac60a106037ab7b6fdd8cb#commitcomment-12833379

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that `lazy` by default follows promises, and `order` is a promise due to lazy loading of packages.

```
library(pryr)
is_promise(order)
#> TRUE
```

The default for `lazy_dots`, as used in `select`, is the opposite.

But there is something else going on here too, where the nature of the special `...` is used to extract unevaluated expressions. While your use of substitute will work in many situations, attempts at renaming as available via `select` will fail.

```
select4(df,foo=x,bar=order)
#> Error in select4(df, foo = x, bar = order) : 
#>   unused arguments (foo = x, bar = order)
```

However, this works

```
select5 <- function(.data, ...) {
  dots<-lazy_dots(...)
  out1 <- select_(.data, .dots=dots[1])
  out2 <- select_(.data, .dots=dots[2])
  list(out1, out2)
}


select5(df,foo=x,bar=order)
#> [[1]]  
#>   foo
#> 1   1
#> 2   2
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>   bar
#> 1   5
#> 2   6
```

As another example, where `substitute` fails more directly, due to lack of carrying an environment, consider

```
vars<-c("x","y") 

select4(df,one_of(vars),order)
#>Error in one_of(vars, ...) : object 'vars' not found

select5(df,one_of(vars),order)
#> [[1]]
#>   x y
#> 1 1 3
#> 2 2 4
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>   order
#> 1     5
#> 2     6
```

The `select4` version fails because it cannot find `vars`, where `select5` succeeds due to `lazy_dots` carrying around the environment. Note `select4(df,one_of(c("x","y")),order)` is okay, as it uses literals.

Comment: Interesting, thanks for looking into this! Are there any other downsides to using substitute? In my real use-case, the argument names have meaning, and I don't think the user would expect to be able to rename them.

Comment: (and since they have meaning, I can't use `select_(.data, .dots = lazy(group1, .follow_symbols = FALSE)` because that would send `group1` into `select_` instead of the user's input.

Comment: If you are only using literals or names in `df`, you should be okay. However, as another example, consider `vars<-c("x","y")`. Your `select4(df,one_of(vars),order)` will fail because it cannot find `vars`, where `select5(df,one_of(vars),order)` will succeed. But, `select4(df,one_of(c("x","y")),order)` is okay as it uses literals.

Comment: Oh got it. Hm, I really do want it both ways -- for it to somehow know not to use `base::order`, but still use `vars` in your example.

Comment: If you've got time, can you take a look at my second update @A.Webb? Does that look like a viable fix?